# tokenReward.transferFrom does not work?

Tags: solidity, ether, remix, fallback-function

I've been struggling with how to do this for quite some time and hoping this community could help.

I know that it should be added or something similar, so tokens balance of the investor address can be changed after investment.

[image]

I tried to modify `buy()` in a few ways by adding this for example:

```
require(tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, numTokens));
require(tokenReward.transferFrom(ASSET_MANAGER_WALLET, msg.sender, numTokens));

require(tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens));

if (tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens))

tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, amount.mul(rate));

if (tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, amount.mul(RATE))) {
       revert();
     }

if (tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender,  numTokens)) {
       revert();
     }
```

No success.

AND THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT !

Without this line of code,

> require(tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender,
>   numTokens));

I could send eth and balanceOf and amountRised were CORRECTLY CALCULATED BUT THE INVESTOR BALANCE WAS NOT CORRECT.

After adding this line of code, require(tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens)); 
I can not do anything. When sending eth to crowdsale, I get this from Myetherwallet,
[image]

Is there anyone here who could help solve this problem. Thank you, Robert

Token Contract
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x2aa448505f3ba5359e2537113e0fe1293aea9ecb#code

Crowdsale Contract
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf70142870fe11e39af3539005e5f02b31e60fb4c#code

Comment: You need to rephrase your question, I couldn't understand what is your problem, you say too many things but nowhere your problem is stated clearly, for instance `buy()` function should be in the body of your question.

Comment: Hi, why can't send eth to crowdsale contract after adding a line  
require(tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using an external owned account as `tokenReward`.

In etherscan page of your [token sale](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf70142870fe11e39af3539005e5f02b31e60fb4c#readContract) the `tokenReward` address is [`0x79b67dff9fb21d2550937d879ec2eacb2f377da0`](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x79b67dff9fb21d2550937d879ec2eacb2f377da0) which is a regular non contract account.

Since you can only modify the `tokenReward` address in the constructor the only option left is to redeploy your sale contract.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean deploy again the same the crowdsale contract. 
Can You be more specific because I do not really understand how to do it. Robert

Comment: The constructor of your token sale `ParadiseTokenSale` has a parameter `addressOfTokenUsedAsReward` that should point to your token `ParadiseToken`. You cannot fix it in your deployed contracts because the code doesn't allow it, you will have to redeploy them again.

Comment: You were right. The problem was external owned account as tokenReward.
I changed to ParadiseToken. It works but the investor's balance is incorrect.